# What does "fill in" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> There are still plenty of details to fill in...

I searched online dictionaries for meaning of [fill in](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fill-in) but I didn't find any fit meaning.
So, could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> Would you jump off a skyscraper on the basis that the clash between
>   general relativity and quantum theory means there are serious problems
>   with our theory of gravity? It makes no more sense to question the
>   reality of evolution because scientists are still debating about some
>   of its finer aspects than it does to question the existence of gravity
>   for the same reason. **There are still plenty of details to fill in** but,
>   as surely as dropped objects fall, life has and continues to evolve.
>   https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn13717-evolution-myths-yet-more-misconceptions/

Comment: Have you tried googling: **fill in the details?**  
   https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fill+in+the+details

Comment: I did, but I don't think there is any relationship between the text above and the link you've mentioned.

Comment: The link mentioned above explains the act of filling in the details, but not the condition of having details to fill in. Its example is very literal, while the usage above is more figurative. It might be difficult to make the leap between the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say there are details to fill in, we mean there are missing details that need to be added to our understanding of a situation. We have a general idea about something but there are still questions about some of its finer aspects. You can think of the questions as holes or gaps in our knowledge. When we answer these questions we are 'filling in the details' - filling the holes and closing the gaps.